# How to run one script for display of two pivot tables in one HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

For display of one pivot table, I integrated javascript in my html page from source https://rwjblue.github.io/pivot.js/.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/subnav.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/accounting.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/pivot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/pivot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/jquery_pivot.js"></script>
```

Script pivot.js provides the input, the data and structure of a pivot table. Script jquery_pivot.js processes the input, builds and publishes the pivot table and filter. It works. Now, I want to display a second pivot table with a different dataset and structure on the same html page. It did not work.

What I did:

1. I duplicated the script file pivot.js, renamed the copies to pivot1.js and pivot2.js, and changed the code for a different dataset and structure.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/pivotTable1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/pivotTable2.js"></script>

   // e.g. pivotTable1.js for pivot table 1:

   var fields = [...]

   function setupPivot(input){
       input.callbacks = {afterUpdateResults: function(){
           $('#results1 > table').dataTable({...}); // originally ('#results');
       }};
   $('#pivotTable1').pivot_display('setup', input); // originally ('#pivot-table');
   };

   $(document).ready(function() {
       setupPivot({url:'./data.csv', fields: fields, rowLabels:[...], summaries:[...] })
   });
   ```
2. On my html page, where the pivot tables shall be displayed, I wrapped each part by a div with a class 'pivot' and assigned an id for a table, e.g. 1. I changed relevant div id's and added the table no, e.g. 1.

   ```
   // e.g. for pivot table 1:

   <html>
       <body>
           <div id="1" class="pivot">
               <div class="subnav">
                   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Columns<b class="caret"></b></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu stop-propagation">
                               <div id="row-label-fields1"></div>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Filters<b class="caret"></b></a> 
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu stop-propagation">
                               <div id="filter-list1"></div>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Values<b class="caret"></b></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu stop-propagation">
                               <div id="summary-fields1"></div>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Group Values<b class="caret"></b></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu stop-propagation">
                               <div id="column-label-fields1"></div>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <div id="pivot-detail1"></div> <!--- gets the filter list from jquery_pivot.js --->
               <div class="space"></div>
               <div id="results1"></div> <!--- gets the field values from jquery_pivot.js --->
           </div>
       </body>

       <!-- jQuery
       ================================================== --> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Pivot.js 
       ================================================== -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/subnav.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/accounting.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/Pivot.js/pivot.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/utils.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/pivotTable1.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/pivotTable2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pivot/jquery_pivot.js"></script>

       <!-- Datatables.js
       ================================================== -->     
       <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/DataTables/FixedHeader-3.1.4/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/DataTables/datatables.js"></script> 

   </html>
   ```
3. In script jquery_pivot.js, I wrapped the original function in an each function in order to get all div id's of html class 'pivot'. I checked the script runs twice by alerts put at the beginning and the end of the script. I had 4 alerts, so it run for each table.

```
        // get table id's, append original var names by div pivot id and replace the original var in original code by new var: 

        var my_resultsDivId;
        var my_pivotDetailsDivId;
        var my_tableId;
        var my_resultRows;
        var my_filterList;
        var my_rowLabelFields;
        var my_columnLabelFields;
        var my_summaryFields;
        var my_selectConstructor;

        $('.pivot').each(function () {
            my_resultsDivID = 'results' + this.id; // e.g. 'results' is the original var name
            my_pivotDetailDivID = 'pivot-detail' + this.id;
            my_tableDivID = 'pivotTable' + this.id;
            my_resultRows = 'result-rows' + this.id;
            my_filterList = 'filter-list' + this.id;
            my_rowLabelFields = 'row-label-fields' + this.id;
            my_columnLabelFields = 'column-label-fields' + this.id;
            my_summaryFields = 'summary-fields' + this.id;
            my_selectConstructor = 'select-constructor' + this.id;

            alert(this.id); // check which id is processed

            (function( $ ) {...})( jQuery );  // original code

             alert(this.id + ' done'); // check script is actually processed for each id one after the other
        });
```

Result:
Unchanged, only table 2 is displayed, that one, which script pivotTable2.js  is listed last in my html java scripts. 
When I change the order of scripts and put pivotTable1.js last, table 1 is displayed, but within the div for table 2. In addition, then table 1 has no design and functions supplied by DataTables. Even when I remove the script  pivotTable2.js from my html, table 1 is displayed on the page at table two's place, and has no table design. 
How can I improve? Any help and comment appreciated very much.

Comment: So in both of your js files you are reusing the function name `setupPivot`? If that is the case, as a quick fix experiment, I would rename one them and call it in the same js file. If this works, then you at least know what is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I reuse the function named setupPivot. I now tried `function setupPivot1(input){...};` I get the same result: Table 2 is displayed. That's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function in ONE js file to create multiple pivot tables. Technically, you don't need to set fields1 and fields2 as variables, instead you can pass the data directly into the function but I kept it that way to stay similar to what you already have. The only additions to your function is now you simply pass the reference to the data table and pivot table as parameters (outside of the {}).

```
var fields1 = [...];
var fields2 = [...];

function setupPivot(input, data_table_obj, pivot_table_obj){
    input.callbacks = {afterUpdateResults: function(){
        $(data_table_obj).dataTable({...}); // originally ('#results');
    }};
    $(pivot_table_obj).pivot_display('setup', input); // originally ('#pivot-table');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    setupPivot({url:'./data.csv', fields: fields1, rowLabels:[...], summaries:[...] },'#results > table', '#pivotTable');

    setupPivot({url:'./data.csv', fields: fields2, rowLabels:[...], summaries:[...] },'#results1 > table', '#pivotTable1');
});
```

---

Comment: I first tried exactly your code and get my second table displayed, but improperly without table design. I changed your code as I edited to you, and get the second table displayed properly, but not the first table. I change the order of setupPivot, table 2 first, and I get the second table displayed improperly.

Comment: Correction: I change the order of setupPivot, table 2 first, and I get the first table displayed, but improperly.